# AngularJS: Object in ng-repeat not displaying object updates

Tags: angularjs

I have this loop displaying all the possible questions I want on screen. I append to this list using a directive and these updates display fine.

```
    {{Questions}}

        <div id="items" style="border: 3px solid; border-radius:5px; border-color: #808080; min-height: 500px; padding: 10px;">
            <div question-type ng-repeat="Question in Questions track by $index"></div>
        </div>
```

However, when I click on a question I then display the contents for that question elsewhere on the page with a editable fields so you can modify it.

You can see in the above code I am displaying the Questions json object to the screen above the loop, and this correctly displays my updates as I'm typing, but the contents of the loop does not. The questions in the loop will stay as they did when they were created and not update.

Any idea why the Object appears to be updating but it is having no affect on the ng-repeat using it?

EDIT

Here is the directive I am using with the ng-repeat

```
app.directive('questionType', function ($http, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, model) {

            switch (scope.Question.inputType) {
                case 'checkbox':
                    //element.append('<input type="checkbox" ng-model="Question.checked"/><button ng-if="input.checked" >X</button>');
                    break;
                case 'text':
                    var strElm = '<div class="form-group" data-ng-click="selectProperties($index)"><label class="col-lg-12 control-label" style="text-align: left;">' + scope.Question.label + '</label><div class="col-lg-12"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=' + scope.Question.placeholder + ' readonly></div></div>';
                    var compiledHtml = $compile(strElm)(scope);
                    element.append(compiledHtml);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

SECOND EDIT

I was not binding correctly. Got it working with this line -

```
var strElm = '<div class="form-group" data-ng-click="selectProperties($index, obj.Questions)"><label class="col-lg-12 control-label" style="text-align: left;" >{{Question.label}}</label><div class="col-lg-12"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=' + scope.Question.placeholder + ' readonly ng-model="Question.placeholder"></div></div>';
```

Comment: how do you bind the Question item in your ng-repeat element? Is the question-type directive? Avoid the use of other directives on same ng-repeat tag, this could cause unespected behaviors, use a directive with parameter as child of ng-repeat tag

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer to show the directive being used and how it's being displayed. Any ideas how I could change this?

Comment: the directive hasn't any binding, how can be updated? You need to bind the question label to some tag o text to be updated by angular. In this cases is better using directive with controller and template insthead of a link one

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I am pretty new to this so excuse my ignorance. How can I bind it so that it will display? I have tried adding in ng-model="Questions[$index]" into my  appended html but that is not working.

Comment: Refer to the Create directive paragraph, to create a directive with is own scope and that take a parameter https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive, the final result would be as i post on my answer, you only miss the directive definition

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I got it working in the end, using the method I posted. It was just a case of not binding correctly with ng-model, which you made me realise. I'll try doing it the other way you suggested next time I do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your ng-repeat creates an isolated scope.

Put Questions inside an empty object and use that.

example:

```
$scope.obj = {};

$scope.obj.Questions = your questions json.
```

In your HTML you have to refer to it in your ng-repeat as `obj.Questions`

Comment: Hi I tried this but it has the same result. I'm aware of the isolated scope problem and how putting something in an object solves that, but Questions is already an object so I don't think this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="Question in Questions track by $index">
    <question-type question="Question"></question-type>
</div>
```

And change your directive definition too

Comment: Hi, I tried this and had the same result. I updated my question with the directive I'm using if that helps. Maybe I'm doing something wrong there.